# How to upload to S3 bucket using React Native?

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3

```
      const base64String = await RNFS.readFile(uri, 'base64')
  const myBuffer = Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64')

  logger.info('base64', base64String)
  const parallelUploads = new Upload({
    client,
    params: {
      Bucket: s3Media.bucket,
      Key: `${bucketId}/${filename}`,
      Body: myBuffer,
      ContentType: contentType
    },
    queueSize: 4,
    partSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
    leavePartsOnError: false
  })
```

i get valid base64 and buffer and uri is path to the media image but even when its completed its not valid.